# 2020 Macbook Air M1 won't push 3440x1440 through Belkin Dock mini

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, thunderbolt, dock

I'm pushing from my 2020 Macbook Air M1 through a Belkin Thunderbolt 3 Dock mini that is HDMIed into my 34 inch screen and my display settings are only giving me options for 1920x1080 and 1280x720 when I'm looking to get 3440x1440. Does anyone know whether this is a limitation of the dock or are there settings that will enable to push 3440x1440?[image]

Comment: It works directly to the 34” screen from the laptop?

Comment: Check the spec of the Hub to see what version the HDMI output is. If it's not v2.0, then you won't get 4K at 60Hz -- you'll need a lower refresh rate. The same for the cable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try RDM: https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM. It can show more options than the built-in resolution picker. If it doesn't work even with RDM (doesn't show up in RDM menu), it is probably a dock limitation.

I've had good luck with RDM for seeing unexposed resolutions so it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try BetterDisplay (https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay) to show more resolutions:

> Convert your internal and natively connected external displays to smoothly-scaled HiDPI displays on Apple Silicon - now even without mirroring a dummy (displays with notch, HDR, HDCP, high refresh rate fully supported)! *

Also, I'd verify the specs of the dock to see what the HDMI port can output.

Then I'd check the HDMI cable to confirm the version to make sure it can support a 2k or 4k resolution.